# Uploading images using Crate blob table

Tags: blob, crate

Is it really possible to upload image using Crate Blob table. i found this link (https://crate.io/docs/reference/blob.html) which is able to upload text on blob table.

Similarly, i am looking to upload images to crate Blob table. I didn't find the way to do this. Can somebody help on this.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible to upload all kind of binary files including images to a blob table.

For example with curl you can use:

```
 curl -v -XPUT localhost:4200/_blobs/foo/3b31733584613967a14d5a9ef530fbdc750c09cf --data-binary @/tmp/screenshot.png
```

(The hash has to be generated beforehand, for example using sha1sum:

```
sha1sum /tmp/screenshot.png
```

The python client for example also has built-in blob support:

https://crate.io/docs/reference/python/blobs.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it with help of your above information. Added  uploadBlob method on https://github.com/LeisureTime/Crate-php-Client/blob/master/Crate.php.